# Advanced MVC Core Table List with GroupBy options

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, model-view-controller, lambda

Dears, I'm looking for a solution how to create a website with table report which has:

- Filter bar on top,
- Table with search results,
- **Group by options**

What I've reach so far is:
[Part of website printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TTW3.png)

I've a 
`IQueryable<ReportItem>` which returns me a list of objects from sql filtered by any of selected filters above

```
 public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(ReportSearchViewModel search)            
  {
        ReportViewModel vm = new ReportViewModel();
        if (search.MovementDateFrom.HasValue)
            querableList = querableList.Where(x => x.MovementDate >= search.MovementDateFrom.Value);

        if (search.MovementDateTo.HasValue)
        {
            search.MovementDateTo.Value.AddDays(1);
            querableList = querableList.Where(x => x.MovementDate < search.MovementDateTo.Value);
        }
        if (search.selectedCompaniesFrom != null && search.selectedCompaniesFrom.Length > 0)
            querableList = querableList.Where(x => search.selectedCompaniesFrom.Contains(x.FromCompanyId.Value));

        if (search.selectedCompaniesTo != null && search.selectedCompaniesTo.Length > 0)
            querableList = querableList.Where(x => search.selectedCompaniesTo.Contains(x.ToCompanyId.Value));

        vm.drumItems = querableList.ToList();

        vm.filter = search;
        return await Task.FromResult(View(vm));
}
```

How can I do the same to selected **multiple** Group By options:

- returned table will have different size (less columns etc) dynamic??
- ViewModel wont fit for this data

Standard version of report returns list from SQL,
New version is supposed to display elements grouped by  - for instance (Material, Customer...) with SUM of (Quantities)

from 
**Created | Customer | Material | Quantity | StorageLocation**
2019-09-01 | ABC | MAT01 | 3 | 0003
2019-09-15 | ABC | MAT02 | 2 | 0004
2019-09-19 | ABC | MAT02 | 5 | 0004

to

- if selected group by option was (Material)
  **Material | Quantity**
  MAT01 | 3
  MAT02 | 7
- if selected group by option was (Customer)
  **Customer | Quantity**
  ABC | 10
- if selected group by options were (Customer,Material)
  **Customer | Material | Quantity**
  ABC | MAT01 | 3
  ABC | MAT02 | 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not too many columns need to group by , you can simply try below code sample :

```
bool groupByCustomer = false;
bool groupByMaterial = true;


List<Report> result
    = (from r in _context.Reports.AsEnumerable()

    group r by new
    {
        Customer = groupByCustomer ? r.Customer : null,
        Material = groupByMaterial ? r.Material : null,
    }
    into gg

    select new Report
    {
        Customer = gg.Key.Customer,
        Material = gg.Key.Material,
        Quantity = gg.Sum(x => x.Quantity)

    }
).ToList();
```

Not grouped columns value will be `null` , you can use view model with all columns and pass to client , on client you can dynamically hide/delete column when rendering the tables. Of course you can also modify on server side that it's up to you .

Comment: Thank You! This is perfect solution for me!